# Webservice certificate-related error

Tags: java, web-services, certificate

I'm trying to write a webservice client to consume a test service provided by another company, over SSL.  I'm not 'certificate savvy' so I'm hoping this is just something simple that I'm overlooking.  I have three 'stores': one truststore, one keystore for message signing, and one keystore for transport (as outlined in the doc supplied by the webservice hoster).  When trying to access the service, I'm getting the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
```

and at the bottom of the stack trace is this:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Wed Mar 16 19:59:59 EDT 2011
```

That last message sounds like it's saying that a cert is expired.  I've checked every cert that I've got in the three stores and none of them are expired.  So does this message mean that the *server* has an expired cert?  Or have I got something configured screwy??

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I verified that the issue is with the server certificate by adding `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");` to my code.  That way I could see the certificate info that was being sent/received.  The server's cert has expired.  >:\